# How To Read Color Value?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to Reading Color from Android Application. Here I have developed one Application, in which from Camera, I am reading the color. I want to perform some action while reading/catching red color in my camera.

Please guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is that, you can get the Color of an individual pixel of a bitmap using,

[bitmap.getPixel(int x, int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29)

You should have the image as a Bitmap object and should specify the x and y co-ordinates of the pixel for which you want the color.

Bear in mind that, checking pixel-by-pixel is time consuming and not an effective method.